# Javascript data object is populated in a conditional check, but secondary output of specific object variables are undefined?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I know this is some weird async issue, but how would I output the "nid" value? I made a conditional statement to check if "data" is populated it does indeed contain something. So in the next statement I just want to output the internal object variables such as "nid". I know its something to do with async, but I just want to output the variable I need.

Stop linking me to other "duplicate" questions or answers as the solution below does not work as shown in other questions!

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data.nid));
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: because a string is not an object....

Comment: Perhaps you meant to JSON-deserialize `data` first?

Comment: Please include actual text of your code and not pictures of your code

Comment: FYI, [the `JSON.stringify`  method can take parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to make it more human readable.  Try this: `JSON.stringify(data.nid, null, 2)`.  That specifies no custom replacer function, and to indent with 2 spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your screenshot and the output of `data` e.g.

```
["nid":[{"value":334}],...
```

the actual data you are receiving is a string and **not** an object. As such `data` of course does not have a `.nid` property.

You need to parse the string to an object first. As @CherryDT pointed out though you might end up trying to parse an incomplete string. So if you really want to log the data inside the data event handler, wrap the parsing inside a try-catch block.

```
response.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
    let tempData;
    if (data) {
        let error = false;
        try {
            tempData = JSON.parse(data);
        } catch (err) {
            error = true;
        }
        if (!error) {
            console.log(tempData.nid);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The parsing needs to happen on `end` and not on `data`, otherwise you'd end up trying to parse half an object if it came in multiple chunks!

Comment: Additionally... `data = JSON.parse(data);` - This should probably create a new local variable, not over-write the `data` variable.  Otherwise on the next `data` event the `data += chunk;` operation will start making things... go wrong.

Comment: Hell yeah, I didn't see it's an outer-scope variable.